# Emulator for Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Limited for Google I/O)

Tags: android, android-emulator, tablet

When developing Apps for Android, based Tablet (GALAXY Tab 10.1).
Where can I find the resources for it??

and there's a problem connecting GALAXY Tab to my PC,

Answer (score 0):

same place for other android apps?

http://developer.android.com/index.html

and your issue connecting it ot your PC should be a separate question, but have you installed the USB drivers for your Galaxy tab to connect it to your PC yet?  I don't think it is it's own download, but installed when you install the KIES application.